# Shopware6 authentication using Integration

Tags: api, curl, oauth-2.0, shopware

Shopware6 authentication using integration not working properly sometime
Below is my code

```
$authData = array('client_id' => $client_id,
  'client_secret' => $client_secret,
  'scopes' => 'write',
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
);

$url = rtrim($url, '/') . '/api/oauth/token';


$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($authData));
curl_setopt( $curl,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8']
          );

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
exit;
```

it says The user credentials were incorrect, but credential are correct
Can you please help me
Thanks in advance....

Comment: try with curl on terminal to check, `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"client_id":"xyz","client_secret":"xyz"}' \
  http://example.com/api/oauth/token`

Answer (score 1):

I use Guzzle Http Client, and everything works for me properly. I use next code

```
    $httpClient = new Client();
    $postBody = json_encode([
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => $this->sw6AccessKey,
        'client_secret' => $this->sw6SecretKey
    ]);

    $response = $httpClient->post('http://test.com/api/oauth/token', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => $postBody
    ]);
```

In general, your code looks good.

Make sure that credentials are correct and write permission is enabled in Shopware integration settings.

Comment: After using guzzle still getting same issue and permission is also provided

Comment: Crazy, you can debug \Shopware\Core\Framework\Api\OAuth\ClientRepository::getIntegrationByAccessKey() to define reason, why exactly you are not authorized.

Comment: But i don't have control on shop and i am new to shopware i just have shop's client_id and client_secret

Comment: So, just tried your code from your question with my credentials and everything works perfectly. Got correct response with access key inside.
So in my opinion, the credentials that you have are incorrect.

Client id should start from `SWIA`

Comment: I was checked with new integration credential and it has write permission too it not works for some shops any security reasons overthere?

Comment: Sorry, but i have no idea why it is not working, in case credentials are correct.

Comment: @KhusalBerva update your guzzle code here in the question, then only debug is possible or use Logs to pass the error of guzzle request.